# Magento 2 : Save quote

Tags: magento2, quote

What is the Difference between

```
$this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
```

&

```
$quote->save();
```

In below code

```
public function aroundApply_shipping(
        \StripeIntegration\Payments\Api\Service $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        $address,
        $shipping_id = null
    ) {
        if (empty($this->checkoutSession) || empty($this->checkoutSession->getQuote()) || empty($this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId())) {
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/methodcallcheck.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('Your text message');
            $data = $this->request->getBodyParams();
            $token = "";
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "";
            if (isset($data['cart']) && !empty($data['cart'])) {
                $token = $data['cart'];
                $cartId = $this->maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId->execute($token);
                $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($cartId);
                $quote->setRemoteIp($this->_remoteIp->getRemoteAddress());
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
                try {
                    if (count($address) === 0) {
                        $address = $this->expressHelper->getDefaultShippingAddress();
                    }
                    if (!$quote->isVirtual()) {
                        $shippingAddress = $this->helper->getShippingAddress($address);
                        $shipping = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($shippingAddress);
                        if ($shipping_id) {
                            $shipping->setShippingMethod($shipping_id)
                                ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                                ->collectShippingRates();
                            $parts = explode('_', $shipping_id);
                            $carrierCode = array_shift($parts);
                            $methodCode = implode("_", $parts);
                            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $ba */
                            $shippingAddress = $this->inputProcessor->convertValue($shippingAddress, 'Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface');
                            /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $shippingInformation */
                            $shippingInformation = $this->shippingInformationFactory->create();
                            $shippingInformation
                            //->setBillingAddress($shippingAddress)
                            ->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
                                ->setShippingCarrierCode($carrierCode)
                                ->setShippingMethodCode($methodCode);
                            $this->shippingInformationManagement->saveAddressInformation($quote->getId(), $shippingInformation);
                            $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
                            $quote->collectTotals();
                            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: any reason why its like this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: both should work. I checked as well and both line of code working, could you please add whole code ?

Comment: Added code @Pawan

Comment: I doubt that "$this->quoteRepository->save($quote);" used twice can cause issue but its not.

Comment: What you think @Pawan ?

Comment: Not sure but may be issue with `$this->quoteRepository->save($quote);` calling twice. You save quote after all code.

Comment: $cartId = 6;
$quote = $quoteRep->get($cartId);
$quote->setRemoteIp("196.1.36.2");
$quoteRep->save($quote); working
$quote->save(); // working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127194/discussion-between-devhs-and-pawan).

Comment: I just tried above code in external script and it worked for both time.

Answer (score 0):

1. $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);

quoteRepository

The quote Repository class implements CartRepositoryInterface is used to follow Repository Pattern i.e. Edit/Update Or Delete existing entity.
https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/class_magento_1_1_quote_1_1_model_1_1_quote_repository.html

2. $quote

Quote Factory

This object is initialized from $this->quote->create();

It is following factory method which is directly manipulated with database entities and it's commonly used to create new records.

Comment: What is the basic difference between both methods ?
I am just updating & saving quote, which should be ideally used ?

Comment: Ideally you can use the repository, Its recommended for updating the entity.